# What is the maximum size for an HTML canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

Creating a large visualization in HTML.

In Chrome (v. 18), the maximum canvas size is 32,768 pixels high. Is there a way to display a larger canvas?

Where is this limit coming from?

Comment: Well, 32,738 is the upper limit for signed 16bit numbers. That's probably where the limit comes from. Although I find it hard to believe you'll need ~33k pixels for any application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*32,768 = 2<sup>15</sup>* and *2<sup>15</sup> - 1 = 32,767* is the biggest number a `short int` can hold.

So Google Chrome probably uses the datatype `short int` for storing the sizes of a `<canvas>` element.

If you want to display larger `<canvas>` elements, you could try to use multiple ones.
You should also consider another implementation technique if you really need ~33k pixels!

Comment: To be precise, the largest value a signed short can have is **32,767**, 2^15-1.