# Detect maximum canvas size

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to detect the maximum width and height for canvas element? I'm trying to serve different image sizes depending on the user support for that tag

Edit:
Here are more details...

I'm using Three.js with canvas renderer. When passing it a large texture some devices couldn't load them because the canvas size limit (iPhone 4 for example). But it fails silently so i can't do nothing to detect it and load a smaller texture. So i need a way to know what is the max size of the canvas element to load the proper file.

also tried to oversize it like this to catch an error

```
var backCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var img = $('img').get(0);
img.width= 90000;
backCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img,0,0,90000,90000)
```

Comment: What you had tried so far ? Please post your code via www.jsfiddle.net or codepen

Comment: Had you tried this link ???
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259108/what-is-the-maximum-size-for-an-html-canvas

Comment: i dont think this is a problem with the int limit Because is happening with a small texture too in some devices (2048x2048)

Comment: It is well known that some implementation of the 2D canvas have a maximum size, esp. on the iOS devices. E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element
For my own application it would be really great to figure out the limits during runtime...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but unfortunately not using a native browser API.

See my answer in the [Maximum size of a <canvas> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element/53677532#53677532) thread for details.